# undefined return from a class instance - Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just asked this question and i thought it was resolved but it isnt.. so here it is again.. apologies for the double post..

I have a file: block.js:

```
class Block{
    constructor(timeStamp, lastBlockHash, thisBlockData, thisBlockHash){
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.lastBlockHash = lastBlockHash;
        this.thisBlockData = thisBlockData; 
        this.thisBlockHash = thisBlockHash;
        }

    static genesis(){
        return new Block(Date.now(), "---", "This is the genesis block", "hash of the genesis");
    }
}
```

another file: blockchain.js:

```
const Block = require('./block');

class BlockChain{
    constructor() {
        this.chain = Block.genesis();
    }
}

module.exports = {BlockChain};
```

and finally a test file test.js:

```
const BlockChain = require("./blockchain.js");
let blockChainInstance = new BlockChain();

console.log(blockChainInstance.chain);
```

the output of the test.js file is showing "undefined" in place of a genesis block.. this has been a mystery for me since morning.. and i would be immensely grateful if anyone can solve this for me..

Cheers,
al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's the root cause of your issue, but in *blockchain.js* you're basically exporting the class as

```
module.exports = {
    BlockChain: BlockChain
};
```

And so, in *test.js* you should import the class using

```
const { BlockChain } = require('./blockchain.js');
```

Comment: i am not able to reproduce the error i had since morning.. i didnt edit anything but somehow i am not getting the same error.. if anyone is able to reproduce my original error please comment so we can have a chat.. :) cheers.. thanks Petr and everyone who spent some time

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the Block class:

```
  module.exports = class Block { /*...*/ };
```

same for the `BlockChain` class.